# sparklyr and local Spark on YARN-Cluster without Cloudera

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, sparklyr

Have tried this combination without Cloudera but failed.

With Cloudera, I tried following the tutorial [sparklyr: a test drive on YARN](https://www.r-bloggers.com/sparklyr-a-test-drive-on-yarn/)

Wonder if anyone has success without need to use

```
/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.hdfs
/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn
```

And how?

Comment: What part of the tutorial is giving you errors?  Simply these files are needed but do not exist, or some specific error message that occurs at a specific step?  Please help people help you by editing your question to make it more clear what is happening.

Comment: @Paul These are directories specialized to cloudera. I installed hadoop by homebrew, set YARN_CONF_DIR, HADOOP_CONF_DIR to /path/to/homebrew/hadoop/conf in R, do spark_connect("yarn-client"). It didn't work. Hadoop and Yarn are OK. If a use spark come with sparklyr, there is a error like this one: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/85757/how-to-add-the-hadoop-and-yarn-configuration-file.html. Beyond my capacity to investigate, just wonder if any out-of-box solution without cloudera.